# Bash - success or failure - send email first and then exit

Tags: bash, email

I would like to run a bash script on the target server, whenever any command execution fails, I would like to first send email with error details and why it failed and then exit from the program

I have tried redirecting the whole bash script execution to a log file and sending email the log file.

Right now I am getting email with the file.log content only when the script is executed successfully, but I would like to receive email even when it failed also, with the details. Pleas help.

```
exec > file.log 2>&1 

case $(hostname) in
abcd|defg)
blah
blah
;;

ghij|klmn)
blah
eg: command failed here due to file not present
blah
;;

*) echo "Not found"
esac
echo -e "Sending $(cat file.log)" | mailx -s "Status" abcd@abcd.com
```

Comment: You want your script to email if it fails due to syntax errors like a missing `esac`?

Comment: sorry, I corrected the code now. When the whole script execution is successful, it is sending the file.log contents to my email. However, if anything is failed in any one of the case statements execution, it is simply exiting out - but not sending email.

Comment: I copy-pasted your script, replaced the email address with my own, changed `$(hostname)` to `ghij` so it would run the failing branch. When I run it, I get this email: "Sending foo: line 10: blah: command not found. foo: line 11: eg:: command not found [...]". Your posted script works as intended and sends email in both cases (try it and see). Please make sure to test the scripts you post, otherwise you lose important details like how your real script probably has `set -e` which is what is causing this

Comment: [Never use `set -e`.](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105)

Comment: Thanks to "that other guy", I tested my script and its actually working as expected. My aim is situation a) whole script is executed successufully, all the command executed successfully - so successful log sent to email situation b) one of the command failed, even then the whole log should be sent to email. I just tested and its working fine. I am sorry for the confusion, but thanks to the community for jumping in immediately to help !. I really appreciate !!

Answer (score 1):

## Try this:

#### I don't know what command you are using so I used PING:

```
 #!/bin/bash

 status() {
 for hosts in 192.168.1.1 192.168.1.2 192.168.1.3 192.168.1.250; do
    ping -t 1 -c 1 "$hosts";
 if [[ "$?" -gt "0" ]]; then
    echo -e "Host is down: '$hosts'" >> error.log
 fi
 done
 }

 failedornot() {
 while read line; do
    grep -q "down" error.log
 if [[ $? -eq "0" ]]; then
    echo -e "Something went wrong, sending e-mail report to: abcd@abcd.com"
    cat error.log | mailx -s "Status" abcd@abcd.com
    rm error.log
 else
    echo "Everything is fine, executing blabla.sh"
 fi

     done < error.log
 }

 status
 failedornot
```

## Output

```
Host is down: 192.168.1.250
Something went wrong, sending e-mail report to: <username>..
```